# Send StatusCode 400 when "No Records Found"

Tags: php, slim

how to set the StatusCode to 400 in slim v2 when the MySql response is unsuccessful?

```
$app->get('/gg/:user/:pass', 'gg');

function gg($user, $pass) {
                $sql = "...";
                try {
                        $db = getDB();
                        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
                        $stmt->bindParam("user", $user);
                        $stmt->bindParam("pass", $pass);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $gs = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                        if ($gs) {
                            ....
                        } else {
                                http_response_code(400);
                                throw new PDOException('No records found.');
                        }
                } catch(PDOException $e) {
                        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
                }
        }
```

The api returns status error 200 but it should change to statuscode 400 when no mysql data found.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Doesn't work is almost always a useless expression here. What is the expected result and what is the actual result are two important questions you should answer when asking. Create a [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question to get better answers.

Comment: http://docs.slimframework.com/response/status/

Comment: @Url wow, a whole **`two`** posts to your credit and already you toss your weighty rep around. underwhelmed !

Comment: @YvesLeBorg sorry mate,i am new and i don't really care about my rep.I will make better posts in the future when i get some experience. GetLife > GetRep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the slim2 manual the correct approach is:](http://docs.slimframework.com/response/status/)

```
$app->response->setStatus(400);
```

since your inside a function you need to get `$app` in there, there are a couple of ways:

in this case i suggest: http://docs.slimframework.com/configuration/names-and-scopes/

```
$app = Slim::getInstance();
```

Comment: Already tested that. It says: Type: ErrorException
Code: 8
Message: Undefined variable: app

Comment: $app is not in your function scope

Comment: add `$app = Slim::getInstance();` to the function

Comment: Works!Thank you very much!

Comment: well to be honest i have never used slim2 so this is all just based on reading the manual

Comment: I couldn't find that on the manual, i was looking for a wrong one.